# Would using something similar to reentry heating for preflight/postflight decontamination harm the atmosphere?

Tags: science-based, atmosphere, re-entry

The world of Blort enjoys a thriving interstellar trade! But it learned the hard way in the Year of the Chuknik that ignoring the *outside* of an incoming spaceship is bad. Really bad. Plague bad. They discovered that forcing all incoming ships to take an extra lap around the planet scoured all those nasty bacteria and space barnacles right off the hulls of the ships!

But wouldn't you know it, it turns out the Interstellar Trade [Kakistrocracy](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/kakistocracy) (ITK) now requires all the *outbound* ships to go through the same procedure!

Fine... It costs a lot, takes time, it's a hassle, but what have we come to expect from bureaucracy? So now all the incoming and outgoing ships must turn a bit of speed and skip around on the atmosphere generating a breathtaking amount of heat and decontaminate everything.

- I'm processing 10,000 ships total a day. It's a non-stop ribbon of burning glory in our upper atmosphere. We're definitely high enough to be dealing with plasma due to the high-speed compression wave, not friction. We know that at least one of the byproducts is [nitric oxide](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/737592/180871).

**Question:** Will my atmosphere suffer for that many ships decontaminating themselves daily?

- Use Earth as our point of reference.
- I said "extra lap" earlier. At 10,000 trips a day, the extra lap probably won't matter, so don't worry about how long reentry takes. Assume a standard shuttle reentry insofar as we're creating compression waves, plasma, and heat.
- Whether or not trying to decontaminate bacteria and the nefarious space barnacles will result in a *biological* problem is not considered as part of this question.
- If something biological in Earth's atmosphere *could* with that many ships skipping around, that would be within the scope of the question.
- For the purpose of this question, treat each of the 10,000 ships as if they are re-entering the atmosphere (reentry) — but only insofar as they're generating compression waves, plasma, and heat. Whether or not they're landing is not part of this question.
- Yes, if we focus only on science all 10,000 ships want to dance around the equator. Pretend that they do, individually. Please don't take time trying to work out how all those ships might interfere with each other. Let's assume the worst case for the atmosphere.
- For the purpose of this question, ships are shaped like Star Wars imperial destroyers, but scaled to 400 meters long with a cargo displacement of 200,000 tons. The material of the ship is irrelevant as the effects of the material burning off are not considered by this question.

---

**Edit:** All requested details due to launch were specifically excluded from consideration by the original question. All requested details about contamination were also specifically excluded in the original question. Details not involving launch or contamination were addressed in previous edits.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/140945/discussion-on-question-by-jbh-would-using-something-similar-to-reentry-heating-f).

Answer (score 2):

It seems to me there would be no problem if there was another planet with a dense atmosphere but no life in the star system.

The question mentions interstellar trade, so travel between two planets in a star system should be rather easy by comparison with routine interstellar trade.

Our solar system has four giant planets with dense atmospheres, planet Venus with a dense atmosphere, moon Titan with a dense atmosphere, and planet Mars with an atmosphere much thinner than Earth's but possbily thick enough for heating up hulls in the atmosphere.  And as far as we know now, each and every one of those six or seven worlds is totally lifeless.

Star systems vary greatly in their structure, but I think that systems with one inhabited planet with an atmosphere and no lifeless uninhabited planets with dense atmospheres will be rare.  The vast majority of systems should have at least one lifeless planet with a dense atmosphere.

So an incoming ship can zoom around the the atmosphere of a lifeless planet enough to scour the hull, and then go over to the inhabited planet and land knowing it has been decomtaminated (on the outside).  And a ship that takes off from the inhabited planet can go to another planet in the system with atmosphere and zoom around in that atmosphere to scour the hull, and then leave the star system for another one knowing that it has been decontaminated (at least on the outside).

So whenever it is discovered that zooming around in planet Blort's own atmosphere is causing problems to that atmosphere, they can change the rules to move the decontamination laps to the atmosphere of some other planet in that system.  And they won't have to worry about changing or damaging the atmosphere of that planet - at least until and unless life is discovered on that planet.

Answer (score 0):

Let's make some assumptions.

- The planet is completely Earthlike. In fact, it's Earth. So it has Earth's atmosphere, and Earth's annual energy budget from the sun.
- The ships are using the atmosphere to lose their kinetic energy, just like a shuttle.
- The ships are traveling at roughly orbital/escape velocity; the same speed as the shuttle.
- There were 3,120,500,000,000 Joules of kinetic energy that needed to be lost in a typical shuttle <strike>landing</strike> reentry.

Multiply that by 10,000/day, and by 365 days in a year.

So you end up with about 10^19 J added to the atmosphere each year. For comparison, 10^17 J of energy strikes the plane from the sun every second. So that's as much energy as 100 extra seconds of sunlight hitting the earth each year.

Doesn't seem too scary.. if all we're <strike>landing</strike> reentering is space shuttles.

But the shuttle was only about 100 tonnes fully loaded, so multiply that by 2,000 to account for the weight/kinetic energy of the 200,000 tonne ships.

At that point, the 80 seconds becomes 44 days' worth of extra sun-energy into the atmosphere.

That WOULD affect things notably, over a 12% increase in the planet's energy budget for heat.

And that's just the <strike>landings</strike> reentries. If they <strike>vented</strike>[have added a new rule that requires them to vent] the same energy to the atmosphere every <strike>launch</strike>departure, too (about 2 megatons), then that would double it, to a 24% increase in energy.

And it'd perhaps be a even more. About 30% of the energy from the sun is immediately reflected back out to space. The energy from aerobraking, though, would be kinetic energy converted directly into thermal energy in the atmosphere, which would not be immediately radiated away, and this turns that +24%-sun-equivalent to over 30%.

If 30% increase in energy budget sounds not too serious, consider that Anthropogenic Global Warming (AGW) is thought to add an additional 0.6 to 2.4 Watts/square meter of energy from the sun... to the 1,370 Watts each square meter already gets. Call it about 1 Watt in 1,000, or 0.1%, and that's of significant concern.

A **30%** increase would utterly ravage the climate... or perhaps help terraform a frozen planet, which might be the REAL reason they instituted the law in the first place. It would certainly be the only possible sane reason to dump that much energy into the atmosphere.

---

Edit: I don't like this calculation. Using "space shuttles" as one of an intermediary calculation unit is a bit too NASA-hates-metric for me, and I don't feel I can trust the 1-significant-figure of accuracy I'm claiming in my result.

Let's try it from first principles instead.

Mass is the product of 10,000 ships/day, massing 200,000,000 kg each, for 365.25 days.

Earth's escape velocity is 11,186 m/s, which assumes they just *fell* into the planet without any extra thrust.

Multiply by 2 because both <strike>taking off and landing</strike> departing and re-entering.

Kinetic energy = 1/2 m v^2.
= 0.5 * 2 * 10,000 * 200,000,000 * 365.25 * 11,186 * 11,186
= 9 * 10^22 J

Sun absorbed by earth/year: 3.85 * 10^24 J (via https://www.ucdavis.edu/climate/definitions/how-is-solar-power-generated)

So by this calculation, that's only a change of **2.3%**, rather than 30%. Still very notable, but not quite so immediately planet-destroying.

---

And then, there's a whole 'nother set of calculations, if they are using rocketry, to figure out the carbon added to the atmosphere to get 9 * 10^22 of thrust.

A barrel of oil has 6.193 * 10^9 J and releases 4.68 * 10^2 kg of CO2, so that's something like 10^15kg of CO2 into the atmosphere per year from space travel, assuming 100% efficient petrochemical processing and rocketry.

For comparison, Earth's CO2 emissions in 2020 were 34.81 Bn metric tons, or 3.481 * 10^13 kg if I'm doing my math right.

So CO2 emissions would be about **100 times higher** than our own.

Comment: I don't think the mass of the ships is a problem. They will be at reentry speed whether they are loaded or not, so it's more about the surface in contact with air.

Comment: @TheSquare-CubeLaw Mass is important because it is part of the equation for kinetic energy. That energy has to go somewhere: with aerobraking (or indeed, with rocketry!) it goes into thermal energy in the atmosphere. But I was skeptical of my values, so I redid the math without the intermediary units, and it looks like people might survive for a few years! :D

Comment: Can you refocus this to ignore launches? As much as everyone wants to deal with them, they are excluded by the question and for a very good reason - not every ship using aerobraking as a means of decontamination was launched from the planet. I can accept the premise of full deceleration for analysis, but launches are right out. (For the record, everyone is assuming no better tech than we have today when it comes to launches. That's a nice thought - but it's false. My ships aren't using aerobraking because they need it to slow down.)

Comment: @JBH You may have misunderstood the answer, then. It does not cover launches (other than in the last part where it covers the carbon they would add). It ONLY AND SOLELY covers reentries, then doubles it to cover the requirement of doing the same thing for outbound ships as well as inbound ones. If you want to ignore the outbound ships even though the question explicitly asks about them, then just divide by 2.

Comment: `And that's just the landings. If they vented the same energy to the atmosphere every launch, too (about 2 megatons), then that would double it, to a 24% increase in energy.` And every paragraph thereafter depends on that assumption.

Comment: @JBH: I may be misreading, but that multiplication by 2 seems to be required by the question, as it says "all the incoming and outgoing ships". If you now want to remove outgoing ships from the question, then like I said: divide by two.

Comment: `For the purpose of this question, treat each of the 10,000 ships as if they are re-entering the atmosphere...` This question does not contemplate launch at all. The back story reference you're pointing too indicates the existence of inbound and outbound trade, but neither requires landing or launching. Per the back story, this is an effort at decontamination. Even the idea of reentry is a simplification for the question as none of the ships will actually land.

Comment: @JBH: You're right that I've made assumption about the delta-V within the atmosphere (from escape velocity to zero and back); if you have some other, less-obvious delta-V in mind, then you'll need to update the question with it, because I can't answer a question you have not asked.

Comment: @JBH: As it is, I've replaced "landing" and "launch" with "entry" and "departure". The math changes not one whit, but maybe that's enough to satisfy you? If not, then hopefully it at least enables you to clarify what your problem actually IS, since the math my answer does not relate to landing/launch, AT ALL.

Comment: Sophistry. The question specifically states there are only 10,000 reentry events to be considered. All other assumptions are excluded. -1 unless the answer is repaired to address the question *as asked* and not *as assumed.*

Comment: If you don't care about outbound, then delete "But wouldn't you know it, it turns out the Interstellar Trade [Kakistrocracy](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/kakistocracy) (ITK) now requires all the *outbound* ships to go through the same procedure! Fine... It costs a lot, takes time, it's a hassle, but what have we come to expect from bureaucracy? So now all the incoming and outgoing ships must turn a bit of speed and skip around on the atmosphere generating a breathtaking amount of heat and decontaminate everything."

Comment: As it is, you're claiming your question says what it doesn't say, so I guess, vote not to reopen unless the question is repaired to ask what you're claiming it's asking in these comments: reentry only.